# Remove empty acl user from a database on a redshift cluster

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql, privileges

I cannot drop a user from a Redshift cluster due to its presence in some dbs' default ACLs

```
# select * from pg_default_acl;
 defacluser | defaclnamespace | defaclobjtype | defaclacl
------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------
        109 |               0 | r             | {}
```

How can I remove this entry?

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by default privileges granted to other users.

You could try to find out more about the privileges granted to or by the user using https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/user_to_be_dropped_privs.sql